# Set Listviewitem selected when it becomes visible

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview and when the user clicks on a listview item, it's background color is changed. I do that via XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/pressed" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:drawable="@drawable/pressed" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/pressed" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:drawable="@drawable/normal" />
<item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/pressed" />
</selector>
```

And this is my listview:

```
...
<com.example.mb7.sportappbp.UI_Controls.StimmungListview
android:id="@+id/lvAngespannt"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:divider="#00279a"
android:entries="@array/str_Stimmungen"
android:dividerHeight="2dp"
tools:listitem="@layout/lstnotificationcell"
android:headerDividersEnabled="true"
android:footerDividersEnabled="true"
android:layout_weight="1.08"
android:listSelector="@drawable/bkg"
android:layout_height="280dp" />
```

Now the only way I found to raise a touch event, was with this code:

```
Integer mActivePosition = 2;
lstAngespannt.requestFocusFromTouch();
lstAngespannt.setSelection(mActivePosition);
lstAngespannt.performItemClick(
lstAngespannt.getAdapter().getView(mActivePosition, null, null),
mActivePosition,
lstAngespannt.getAdapter().getItemId(mActivePosition));
```

where `lstAngespannt` is my listview.
When I write this code in a button.clicks event, it does work. But what I want is, that this code is executed when the activity becomes visible, so that the listview is shown clicked to the user.
I tried to write this code in `onResume` event of the activity, but it does not work.
How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You have to use setOnItemClickListener

Comment: @Curio To use setOnItemClickListener, I have to throw away the xml and change the whole code. I want it to work with the current structure

Comment: Don't you want to use the xml? Use setOnItemClickListener. Don't you want to use the class code? Use the xml